# how to change border size inside html table?

Tags: html, html-table, border, tr

i got this code for simple table:

```html
<table border="5" bordercolor="#F9864D" style="background-color:#EFEFEF" width="450" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

as you can see, only the outter border thick and the inner thin..
how can i set border size that will affect the whole table so the outter and the inner will be the same?

thank you.

Comment: make border value to one like this border="1"

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the td attribute.

If we make a `customTable` class, we can use a CSS selector to select every `td` element in the table. Now if we want to create more tables we can create a new table with a different class and edit that separately from others.

```css
.customTable {
    border: 5px solid #F9864D;
    background-color: #EFEFEF; 
    width: 450px;
}

.customTable td {
  border: 5px solid #F9864D;
}
```

```html
<table class="customTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where do i put the:

td {
  border: 5px solid #F9864D;
}

?

inside "style" tag?
in the head of the html file?

whats going on if this page already has style coding inside .css files that inserted in the head tag?

how can i set a specific style for this table in a way that will not affect the whole page?

Comment: Hey, I changed my answer to make it more clear, I think you will be able to understand it better this way. I've used a CSS selector to select every table cell in the custom table. If you want to read more about CSS selectors, I find [this w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) very usefull.

Comment: now when i add the class to the table, all the settings applies to the outer border
so i need to add another class to each td?
is there a way to add one class that will affect the whole table tds?

Comment: Yes, that's what this:

.customTable td {
  border: 5px solid #F9864D;
}

piece of code does.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid #F9864D;
}
```

```html
<table style="background-color:#EFEFEF" width="450" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```